# How to register user into firebase registration?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am going to insert my email and password into Firebase Authentication. However, the code that I found on the Internet does not work for me? Below is the code and when I click next button, it goes back to the previous page too, it does not proceed with the next page?

```
public void completeRegis() {

    username1 = username.getText().toString().trim();
    email1 = email.getText().toString().trim();
    psd1 = psd.getText().toString().trim();
    psd2 = reconpsd.getText().toString().trim(); 

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email1, psd1)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    //start profile activity here

                    User user = new User(username1, email1,psd1);

                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(RoleInfo1.this, "Registration successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(RoleInfo1.this, HomePage.class ));
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(RoleInfo1.this, "Database not created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(RoleInfo1.this, "Registration not successful, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        username = findViewById(R.id.usernameregister);
        email = findViewById(R.id.emailregister);
        psd = findViewById(R.id.psdregister);
        reconpsd = findViewById(R.id.reconpsdregister);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very new to android but I recently made a signUp page successfully.

declare a firebase auth instance

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private EditText mName, mEmailField, mConfirmPass, mNewPass;
```

then in onCreate() I declared them as

```
 mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eName);
    mEmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fieldEmail);
    mConfirmPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fieldConfirm);
    mNewPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fieldNew);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

I added a button in the authentication page for signup. Clicking on it starts the signUp  procedure. This is done in onCreate() method

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startSignUp();
        }
    });
```

Then I declare the startSignUp() method as below

```
public void startSignUp(){

    String name = mName.getText().toString();
    String email = mEmailField.getText().toString();
    String newPass = mNewPass.getText().toString();
    String conPass = mConfirmPass.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name) || TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(newPass) || TextUtils.isEmpty(conPass)){
        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Fields Empty" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,newPass).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(! task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "SignUp Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    openAuthetication();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If signUp is successful, it will go back to the authentication page for signing in. This is done in the openAuthetication() method.

```
public void openAuthetication(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Authetication.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: HI, i have used the method that you wrote above, but it keeps going to signup failed :(. Is there another solution?

Comment: Provide a valid email id  ... I once used some random email id it was showing sign upfailed. Also see that you have edited the gradle scripts and added internet access in the  manifest file

Comment: may i know what i need to be added into gradle script? sorry i am new to this

Comment: add these lines in the dependencies section... 

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'

open the manifest file and add this line before the application section 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />